# Hahn-Banach theorem application

Tags: functional-analysis

I don't understand how by Hahn Banach theorem we have the following:

Suppose that there exists $f_1, f_2,..$ holomorphic in a Riemann surface $R$ which is zeros on a sequence of points $x_k$ and non zero on $E$ ($E$ is a subset of $R$ and $x_k$ is not in $E$). So by Hahn Banach theorem there exists $g_i\in Hol(E)$ such that $\Sigma g_if_i=1$.

Comment: Is that a finite sum? if not, what is the metric?